# What will be the media queries for specific devices?

Tags: html, css, responsive-design, media-queries

I am working on responsive design but not getting it properly. I need to write media queries for these devices resolutions are following.

240*320,

240*480,

320*480,

480*800,

480*856

so far i have tried these media queries but its conflicting

```
 @media only screen and (max-width:240px) { /* cover 240px portrait */}

 @media only screen and (min-width:320px) and (orientation : landscape) {/* cover 320px landscape for 240*320 */}

 @media only screen and (min-width : 479px) and (orientation : landscape) {/* cover 480px landscape */}

 @media only screen and (min-width : 480px) and (orientation:portrait) {/* cover 480px portrait */}
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Below is the media queries for standard devices. You can write global styles separately and device specific styles within the defined media.

```
/* Smartphones (portrait and landscape) ----------- */
@media only screen 
and (min-device-width : 320px) 
and (max-device-width : 480px) {
/* Styles */
}

/* Smartphones (landscape) ----------- */
@media only screen 
and (min-width : 321px) {
/* Styles */
}

/* Smartphones (portrait) ----------- */
@media only screen 
and (max-width : 320px) {
/* Styles */
}

/* iPads (portrait and landscape) ----------- */
@media only screen 
and (min-device-width : 768px) 
and (max-device-width : 1024px) {
/* Styles */
}

/* iPads (landscape) ----------- */
@media only screen 
and (min-device-width : 768px) 
and (max-device-width : 1024px) 
and (orientation : landscape) {
/* Styles */
}

/* iPads (portrait) ----------- */
@media only screen 
and (min-device-width : 768px) 
and (max-device-width : 1024px) 
and (orientation : portrait) {
/* Styles */
}

/* Desktops and laptops ----------- */
@media only screen 
and (min-width : 1224px) {
/* Styles */
}

/* Large screens ----------- */
@media only screen 
and (min-width : 1824px) {
/* Styles */
}

/* iPhone 4 ----------- */
@media
only screen and (-webkit-min-device-pixel-ratio : 1.5),
only screen and (min-device-pixel-ratio : 1.5) {
/* Styles */
}
```

More info [here](http://css-tricks.com/snippets/css/media-queries-for-standard-devices/). hope it helps.

Comment: Need some more detail on how to write these?

Answer (score 0):

I wrote up this little article on [media queries for various ios device](http://www.uidesignguide.com/2014/02/24/media-queries-to-target-iphone-3-iphone-4-iphone-5-ipad-2-3-4-in-portrait-phonegap-apps/)s. All of these answers will get you closer. It's up to you figure out the right combination that works for your project.